# Root of website signs user out using forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have discovered that when a user logs into my site e.g. http://www.website.com, they log in okay but when they switch the site by taking out the www's i.e to
http://website.com they are effectively a different user, how can I stop this? Any suggestions. I want the site to point to the full path http://www.website.com, google chrome tends to take the www's out - Internet Explorer is okay (for once).

Comment: Enter your domain name administration panel, configure the CName in order to point both `http://www.website.com` and `http://website.com` in order to redirect them to the same IP

Comment: Do i create 2 CNAme records then? One for each and put the record name as http://www.website.com and http://website.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the below in my web.config file:

```
  <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^website.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.website.com/{R:0}"
                  redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```